# App that provides a keyboard shortcut to mute/unmute the microphone?

Tags: keyboard, microphone, big-sur

Is anyone aware of a third-part app that provides a quick shortcut to toggle mute/unmute state of the built-in microphone?

Comment: do you need app? I am using Apple Script with Automator shortcut to mute/unmute microphone from anywhere in MacOS. That would be easy and convenient too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need an app for this. You can open Automator, and create a service. You can then double-click `Run Applescript` , and type in

```
on getMicrophoneVolume()
    input volume of (get volume settings)
end getMicrophoneVolume

on disableMicrophone()
    set volume input volume 0
end disableMicrophone

on enableMicrophone()
    set volume input volume 100
end enableMicrophone

if getMicrophoneVolume() is greater than 0 then
    disableMicrophone()
else
    enableMicrophone()
end if
```

Then save and go to System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts - Services, search for the name of the Automator file, and add any shortcut you want.

More information can be found [here](https://medium.com/macoclock/how-in-the-bleep-do-i-mute-my-mic-anywhere-on-macos-d2fa1185b13).

Comment: Any idea how to get corresponding notifications?

This is my non-working attempt:

`
on getMicrophoneVolume()
  input volume of (get volume settings)
end getMicrophoneVolume

on disableMicrophone()
  set volume input volume 0
end disableMicrophone

on enableMicrophone()
  set volume input volume 100
end enableMicrophone

if getMicrophoneVolume() is greater than 0 then
  disableMicrophone()
  display notification "Off" with title "Mic"
else
  enableMicrophone()
  display notification "On" with title "Mic"
end if
`